# Iframe don't fits JQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, jquery-ui-dialog

When I try to open a URL using Iframe in a dialog JQuery box, I got this: http://s15.postimg.org/7qzx5y8vv/Sem_t_tulo.png

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/Wqf0mGhZ

I want to make the dialog shows ALL the content, thanks...

**EDIT:**
Hey guys, I achieved this by putting the iframe in a div tag, like this:

```
  <div id="imgWindow" title="this is a dialog" style="display:none;">
      <iframe width="100%" height="100%" id="iframeImg" marginheight="0" frameborder="0>
</iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't go through all of your code, but maybe you
can just add autoResize call to open callback (on Dialog):

```
function openDialog(stringURL) {
    $("#imgWindows").attr("src", stringURL);
    $("#imgWindows").dialog("open", {
        callback: function() {
            autoResize('imgWindows');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: First, thank you for your help. I tried it but it doesn't work =/

Comment: Hey guys, I achieved this by putting the iframe in a div tag, like this:

>>    <div id="imgWindow" title="this is a dialog" style="display:none;">
>>      <iframe width="100%" height="100%" id="iframeImg" marginheight="0" frameborder="0>
>></iframe>
>>    </div>

I cant post this because I have no reputation